# How to implement a hash function that runs before django's hasher?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

We are creating a IOT system using a RPC procedure. The RPC is using a login system that checks against django's user model if the password is correct.

We still want to encrypt the password when sent by the RPC so we thought to send a partial hash to check, basicly having two different password checkers one for django and one for the rpc.

Something like this:

```py
def RPC_pass_check(user, RpcHashPassword):
    return user.check_password(RpcHashPassword)

def djangos_pass_check(user, clearPassNoHash):
    password = hash_used_by_RPC(clearPassNoHash)
    return user.check_password(password)
```

This would mean we need a custom make_password for django too that would 
use hash_used_by_RPC(password) before djangos normal hashing procedures.

How or at least where should we implement such a function?

Comment: Sending a hashed password does not add any security. Use a proper transport level encryption and/or a device token.

Comment: I didnt ask anything about security and we have tls.